# How to triger button onclick on a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one anchor tag and a button inside the same div parent.

Clicking on an anchor need to click the button too via code.

Below is my HTML

```html
<div class="product_list">
    <a class="action tocart primary new_add_to_cart"><span>Add to cart</span></a>
    <button type="submit" id="product-addtocart-button-927" title="Add to Cart" class="main-add-tocart action tocart primary">
        <span>Add to cart</span>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="product_list">
    <a class="action tocart primary new_add_to_cart"><span>Add to cart</span></a>
    <button type="submit" id="product-addtocart-button-928" title="Add to Cart" class="main-add-tocart action tocart primary">
        <span>Add to cart</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Below is the JavaScript code I tried to use

```js
$(document).on('click','.new_add_to_cart',function(){
    var pin = $.cookie('delivery-pincode');
    if(!pin){
        alert("hii2");
    }
    else{
        $(this).closest(".main-add-tocart").trigger("click");
    }
});
```

In the else condition I want the closest button (sibling) to be clicked, I have multiple product(parent divs with the same class .product_list) and I want only click only on the "current" product.

Comment: why don't you use `$(this).next('.main-add-tocart').trigger('click');` instead of ` $(this).closest('.main-add-tocart').trigger('click');`

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Olemon403/csrdg7vh/28/)

Comment: `closest()` looks for parent elements. `.main-add-tocart` is a sibling, so use `next()` instead